# Virtual Directory application web.config conflicting with SharePoint web.config

Tags: windows-server-2003, asp.net, iis-6, sharepoint, virtual-directory

My ASP.NET 3.5 application is created in a virtual directory under a SharePoint website in IIS 6 (Windows Server 2003). This application runs on a separate application pool than that of the SharePoint website. The problem I am facing is that when I try to use `Session` in the ASP.NET application, I am getting a `System.NullReferenceException` because `HttpContext.Current.Session` is `null`. I added a `<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20" />` in the web.config of the ASP.NET application, but this is conflicting with the session configuration in the parent SharePoint website's web.config. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Session state being null is usually a symptom of code that is being used too soon in the event lifecycle. It is unlikely that the SharePoint site is impacting this behavior.

Comment: @JoelEtherton when the application runs in Visual Studio's Debug mode, the session related code works just fine. That's why I suspected that inheritance of SharePoint's web.config had something to do with this issue. The specific error message when I explicitly add a `<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20" />` into the application is the following: `Cannot use 'partitionResolver' unless the mode is 'StateServer' or 'SQLServer'`, which is a result of changing the inherited sessionState from SharePoint, which is based on SharePoint's usage of `SqlSessionStateResolver`.

Comment: It sounds like the 2 apps are attempting to share the same session object. You might try `<remove sessionState>` and then add it back explicitly. Remove might not be enabled for the sessionState key though, so you may need to define the sessionState in your child web.config and make sure that you explicitly undo any attributes set by the SharePoint site.

Comment: @JoelEtherton can you give me a snippet on how to achieve this, perhaps as an answer instead of a comment?